# How to check a related entity exists in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So, I'm needing to check wether an entity exists, and if one doesn't create it.

Currently, my Core Data db is populated by JSON, I get a `Work` object which may or may not contain a `Survey` object. If it contains a survey I populate the survey fields and then attach it to my `Work` like so:

```
let newWorkObj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Work", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Work
let newSurveyObj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Survey", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Survey

//newSurvey.field = obj["field"].string etc...

newWorkObj.survey = newSurvey
```

Then, later , I'm needing to check if a `work.survey` exists...how do I do it?

I already tried adding a `isPresent` field inside the entity, then realised that the application will crash before it even gets to that check (an entity has to *exist* before anything can be checked inside it...)

Hopefully I will be able to do something like

```
 if work.survey.EXISTS  {

     //sit back and chill

 }else{

     //make a new entity

 }
```

Everything I have seen assumes I am searching for multiple objects and likes to use `NSPredicate`, surely there's a simpler way of checking wether an entity exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Work entity has a to-one relationship with your Survey entity, and that you defined it something like:

```
@NSManaged var survey: Survey?
```

in your Work class, then you should be able to check if it's set by writing:

```
if work.survey != nil {
    // sit back and chill
} else {
   // make a new entity
}
```